# Crm custom workflow dynamic variable issue

Tags: workflow, dynamics-crm

I wrote a few custom workflow activities and from the browser i used several dynamic variables to populate input properties, for example like **{dynVar1} / {dynVar2} / {dynVar3}**, but after publish it is changed as **{dynVar1}{dynVar1}**. How can this be solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a fix in Rollup2:

- When you click **Set Properties** in a workflow on a custom workflow activity, static text is deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I fully understand your intent. Are you using / as a delimiter?
Consider escaping the character e.g. / or replacing it with another less problematic character like a pipe | or use xml as an input string.